# Right approach for simple tracker in Android?

Tags: android, logging, service, background

For personal training and learning purposes, I would like to create a very basic Android app that can do two things:

- connect to my heart rate sensor belt and log the heart rate
- at the same time log my location

The goal is to open the app, press "START" when I begin running or cycling, then press "STOP" when I come home. No need to show anything in between, the screen does not need to stay on, I just want the logged data (that I'm going to export to my webserver in the next step). So I just want to start logging and then put the phone away without the logging stopping.

As I'm just starting with Android development I would like to know if I'm on the right track with the overall architecture:

Should I use a Foreground or a Background Service? Do I need an additional thread for the START/STOP toggle button UI? It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction and give me a brief overview of what the overall architecture looks like so that I have a starting point for getting into the matter, I'm sure I can figure out the details (connect to the sensor, get the position) by myself.

BTW: I'm on Android 9.1

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use a Foreground or a Background Service?

Foreground services are required to display a notification, such as music players or VPNs. And since I assume you don't care about timing, you probably want to have background service otherwise look into AlarmManager, [see here for more info](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)

> Do I need an additional thread for the START/STOP toggle button UI?

In Android, the overall architecture is not as clear as MVC. Your service is going to be running as its separate thread from which you send the location and heart rate data (look into Intents). It should look something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null, this,
            YourBackgroundService.class);
intent.putExtra("debug", false);
intent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiverListener);
startService(intent);
```

Then in your MainActivity, which if you started out with a sample project in Android Studio it would have already generated a few things, you would have a `onReceiveResult()` method to parse the data as its coming in.

The sample projects given by Google should suffice for what you're trying to do.

This is a pretty broad question but we all have to start somewhere.

P.S.: Extra tips, if you don't seem to be getting any location data remember to add it to your permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`. And don't forget to include your service in the same file as well.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got the idea and will dig through the docs and samples now. Yes, it is a broad question, but now I know what I have to look when diving into the subject 